# Trying to find a comparison between two dates that both have formulas, and return a value

Tags: excel, date, comparison

I am trying to compare two dates - a cancellation and a sold date.  If the sold date is greater than the cancellation date, I need the value to be two other cells.  If it is cancelled, it needs to show as blank.  I have tried using several different formulas, but the result is not correct.

```
=IF(LEN(N125=0),F125&G125,IF(LEN(N125>=E125),0,IF(LEN(E125>=N125),F125&G125)))
```

`=IF(N125=0,F125,G125)` - this just comes back with cell G125

```
=IF(LEN(N125=0),F125&G125,IF(LEN(N125>=E125),0,IF(LEN(E125>=N125),F125&G125)))

IF(LEN(N125=0),F125&G125,IF(LEN(N125>=E125),0,IF(LEN(E125>=N125),F125&G125)))
```

`IF(N125=0,F125,G125)` - this just comes back with cell G125

I expected the outcome to be blank after comparing the cancellation date to the sold date.  Instead it comes out with Sold: Ulrich

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the formula (`Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula`) to see if it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: Difficult to help you with the information provided. I have no idea what is in the cells you are referencing. Suggest you read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: `LEN(N125=0)` should be `LEN(N125)=0`

Comment: I actually do not think you need `LEN`.  I think you should do `=IF(N125="",F125,G125)`

Comment: @Melissa You had typed 5 lines of formulas.. but there is only 2 unique formulas.. line 3 - 5 refers to repeated formula.. is this intended ?

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! I figured it out.  =IF(LEN(M125)=0,G125,IF(M125>E125,0,IF(E125>=M125,G125)))